# Find the equation of a hyperbola, given a point on it and asymptotes

Tags: geometry

I have to find the equation of a hyperbola having a center of symmetry $A(-1,0)$. The point $P(1,1)$ belongs to hyperbola and it has parallel asymptotes to the lines of equation $y=x$ and $x=0$. I found the asymptotes of equations $x=-1$ e $y=x+1$, but how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Your $y$ must tend to $\pm\infty$ for $x\to-1$ (vertical asymptote) and $y-(x+1)$ must tend to $0$ for $x\to\pm\infty$. A simple equation doing the job is
$$
y-(x+1)={k\over x+1},
$$
where $k$ is some constant. To find $k$ just remember that point $P$ belongs to the curve.